# Is it possible to get the size of or resize a running program?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I would like to 'overlay' my application on top of another one, which would require me to resize that other program based on the size of mine. I'm currently using Flutter for my (cross-platform) application, and need to resize that other program based on the dimensions of my application.

In Flutter, I start a new process with `Process.start("executable path")` to start running the 'other program'. This creates a child process, but its window size and positions are not constrainable via my application.

I hope my 'problem' is a bit clear. Is there a way to achieve what I want in:

- 1: Flutter only (or perhaps another cross-platform framework?)
- 2: If not, how could I accomplish this using native APIs?

Comment: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` ?

Comment: No, I mean of a different program, not the current program where the context belongs to